# How to find control in gridview with extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, extension-methods

I am trying to find dropdownlist inside a gridview on pageload. i am currently using extention method. here is my extention method code

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Control FindByID(this Control root, string ID)
        {
            if (root.ID == ID)
            {
                return root;
            }
            foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
            {
                Control foundControl = FindByID(control, ID);
                if (foundControl != null)
                {
                    return foundControl;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and on page load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                 Control controlToFind = GridView1.FindByID("DropDownList3");
                 DropDownList dropDownList3 = controlToFind as DropDownList;
                 string a = dropDownList3.Text;
         }
```

but getting null reference exception 
please help and kindly suggest any other best method.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at your `foreach` loop and step through each iteration. The control isn't being found, so you need to check why. This is infinitely more useful than asking anyone here why it may not be working, because we can't see your controls.

Comment: Even if it would work, what `DropDownList` in the `GridView` do you want to find? The one in the first row or in the last or one between? Use the right `NamingContainer`(`GridViewRow`), for example by using `GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("DropDownList3")`, instead of this error-prone approach.

Comment: also show your asp `MarkUp` so that we can see if you are using the correct assignment in your template `DropDownList dropDownList3 = row.FindControl("DropDownList3") as DropDownList;` notice where I have `row` have you thought about doing the find on the `GridView1_RowDataBound` event.. how else would you know which row in the gridview was selected in regards to the dropdown...?? or look at `GridView1_RowUpdating` event.. the look up the order of events for Page_Load.. when you think that the datagridview will be available at page load.. it actually is

Comment: GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList3") as GridView  but you should know dropdownlist is in which column